# Select within a column in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, filter

I have a table where in a column there are titles. I would like to run a query in PostgreSQL, which helps me to select those titles that contain a particular word. (e.g. select every title that contains 'You', so it would give back I Love You, You Are The Best, How Are You?).

I have tried to use LIKE:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE title LIKE ('You');
```

But it still gives back zero result, because it only accepts exact matches:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE title LIKE ('I Love You');
```

Could you please help me how can I solve this issue?

Thank you!

Comment: You need to use wildcards with "like", as  in `where title like '%you%' `

Comment: `LIKE` and its case insensitive version `ILIKE` will not be able to adequately search for words; for example, `ILIKE '%you%'` will match any title with the letters "you" in sequence, including "your" and "young." To do a word match, it will be necessary to use a more powerful pattern matching method, regular expressions. The expression `title ~* '(^|[\W])You([\W]|$)'` will do a case insensitive search of `title` and return `true` if "you" is found without any adjacent word characters.

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot for both answers!

Comment: After your question has an acceptable answer, please mark it as such. This gives credit in the form of repution points and, more importantly, allows the community to exclude acceptably answered questions from searches so that those that need additional attention can be more easily identified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query will perform a case insensitive search for titles that contain the word "You" but not words that just contain "you" somewhere within them:

```
SELECT *
  FROM table
  WHERE title ~* '(^|\W)You(\W|$)';
```

The regular expression `\W` matches non-word characters. The expression `(^|\W)` matches either the beginning of the text or a non-word character; likewise, `(\W|$)' matches either a non-word character of the end of the text.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [wildcards](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-LIKE):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE title LIKE ('%You%');
```